# replace style with jquery on div within iframe crossdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've an iframe with code that looks like this:

```
iframe#someID

html

head

body

first div
```

iframe points to file on the other domain. I want to replace styling of the div, effectively putting background-color:transparent; instead of color it already has.

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to change the css of your div, or the content of your iframe ?

Comment: AFAIK not unless they reside on the same domain

Comment: but why? iframe loads content into the page, why I can't manipulate content after it has been loaded? why does it matter which domain it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, cross-site-manipulation is fortunately not possible.
To change the contents of an iframe on the same domain, however, have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/contents/#example-1